# Is it possible to design a 4-pin to 24-pin atx molex converter?

Tags: voltage-regulator, zener, atx

first of all I am a real novice in electronics but according to my circuits and electronic classes I think this should be possible:

I want to use a 4-pin ATX cable as a power input in order to generate 24 outputs. Basically, my idea consists in using zener diodes.

Having 12Volts as input and then a 5Volts zener diode I should be able to have a +5V output, then connecting this output to a 3.3Volts zener diode I should be able to have a +3.3V output.

Here's a circuit I've barely drawn:

[image]

My question is how would I deal with the -12V output? And also once all voltages are tested and wrapped in the 24-pin connector, How safe would be connecting a motherboard to this result?

Comment: There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar. It's very easy to use. Add in an in-line schematic.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but I've posted this question via mobile app since I don't have a desktop around me

Comment: With the 10K resistors you show on your drawing, you will only be able to draw well under 1 mA from each zenered output.  If you want to draw any significant power from the 5 volt and 3.3 volt outputs, you MUST use a voltage regulator - preferably a switch mode type.

Comment: Well what I'm actually trying to do is using a PSU's 4-pin 12V output, to actually feed the motherboard via the 24-pin input. If I understand properly what you are saying is that I have to design a switch mode voltage regulator on the zener ends?

Comment: Don't use the Zeners.  Instead, use two DC-DC converters, one 12 V to 5 V, and the other 12 V to 3.3 V (and watch the power/current requirements for each voltage, as well as the current availabe from your 12 volt source!)

Comment: I think that the current is the key point here. I suppose I could determine the motherboard, the CPU, the memories and the HDD current requirements. But then how am I going to determine how much current should flow on every single output? I would need to test currents in the 12, 5 and 3.3V outputs

Comment: Also the power capability of the 4 pin extension is limited by design, depending on the exact supply you're using. Even if you make something that makes it into what you want to have at the (high) currents required, there's no saying on a forum to a conceptual question like this if the power supply will actually even let you do this.

Comment: Good point. The power supply I was trying to adapt is a HP DPS-1200FB Common slot server psu. It has only 12V outputs.

Comment: You want to power an entire computer from this "converter"? Even if you were to use DC/DC converters, the 4-pin connector probably can't supply enough. There's a reason an ATX PSU connector has so many wires; all those doubled up supply rails are for more current capacity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to power a pc from a regulated 12 Volts, you should look into a compact SMPS setup. Or you know, just use a commercial product like a Pico PSU. Completely depends on how much power you need.

[image]

As far as using Zener Diodes, based on typical ATX current needs, you will need a huge Zener or heatsinking. It's not even close to ideal. Using a Zener Regulator calculator, a 500mA load at 12V in, 5V Out, will require the Zener to drop 2.55 Watts in heat.

Linear regulators would be **much better**. ***Switching regulators the best.***

For -12 Volt, you will need a voltage inverter. But -12V is a legacy voltage on ATX supplies for normal PCI cards. Not really used. It depends on what you have connected. Many times it can be skipped on modern motherboards.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I thought that the discontinued pin was the -5V one, required for some ISA Cards.

Comment: -5 was discontinued. -12 is required but unused 90% of the time. They will phase it out eventually.